# How to send IFormFile to Web API as part of ViewModel object

Tags: rest, api, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have .NET Core Web App with the following controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Update(StudentDetailsViewModel vm)
    {           
        var tokenNo = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Token");
        vm.ID = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Session.GetString("StudentId"));

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", tokenNo);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var putStudentUrl = _appSettings.Value.Apis.GSRTCApi.Url + _appSettings.Value.Apis.GSRTCApi.StudentsEndpoint + vm.ID;

        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();

        var stringData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vm); 

        var contentData = new StringContent(stringData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var response = await client.PutAsync(putStudentUrl, contentData); // contentData);


        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

The controller calls my Web API and everything works fine until I upload a file through my html form. When this happens the file is picked up in the IFormFile property of the StudentDetailsViewModel on the client side but when the API call is made the whole object is null. The API controller is:

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Put(int? id, [FromBody]StudentViewModel student)
{
    // API operations here
}
```

My suspicion is that I am not serializing the StudentDetailsViewModel object properly since I have a property IFormFile, which is an interface. However, I am not sure exactly how I need to customize the Json.Newsoft object.

Comment: Include the model and calling JS.

Comment: I don't have JS code is is just a form with asp tags

Answer (score 12):

For sending `IFormFile`, you need to use `FromForm` which is default when you remove `FromBody` and `MultipartFormDataContent`.

Here are complete steps:

1. Web App Model

```cs
public class StudentDetailsViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
```

2. Web App Controller

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Update(StudentDetailsViewModel vm)
{

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var putStudentUrl = @"url";
    byte[] data;
    using (var br = new BinaryReader(vm.File.OpenReadStream())) 
    {
        data = br.ReadBytes((int)vm.File.OpenReadStream().Length);
    }
    ByteArrayContent bytes = new ByteArrayContent(data);
    MultipartFormDataContent multiContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    multiContent.Add(bytes, "file", vm.File.FileName);
    multiContent.Add(new StringContent(vm.Id.ToString()),"Id");
    multiContent.Add(new StringContent(vm.Name), "Name");
    var response = await client.PutAsync(putStudentUrl, multiContent); 
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

3. Web API Model

```cs
public class StudentViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
```

4. Web API Controller

```cs
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Put(int? id,StudentViewModel student)
{
    using (var stream = new FileStream(@"file path", FileMode.Create))
    {
        await student.File.CopyToAsync(stream);
    }
    return Ok();
}
```

Pay attention to `multiContent.Add(bytes, "file", vm.File.FileName);`, the second parameter is the name for `IFormFile` field.

Comment: I have a virtual object property as part of my model which I cannot send to the API when I used [FromForm] instead [FromBody]. In addition, it does not seem like a very elegant solution to me since I need to add every single property to multiContent.

Comment: Not working for me.  I get 415 unsupported media type on my API controller.

Comment: `multiContent.Add(bytes, "file", vm.File.FileName);` -worked for me, it being a `ByteArrayContent ` as opposed to `StreamContent`. Although not sure if `StreamContent` would work as well.